# moment.IsSame returning wrong result

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs

I am using the `moment isSame` which is returning false for two dates which are same,

```
moment(new Date('2070-07-27T21:59:59.999Z')).isSame(moment(new Date('2070-07-27T23:00:58.000Z')), 'day');
```

The above returns false though same day, Any help is appreciated

What alternative and accurate method can be used if this doesn't work

Comment: what timezone are you in? perhaps those two times are either side of midnight, like if you are in UTC+1 or UTC+2 - what happens if you drop the `Z` from those two times?

Comment: Thanks,
Yes, I am in UTC+1 
Works if `Z` is dropped but I don't think I can implement that way

Comment: so, technically, moment is correct, because in your timezone, those are not the same day - problem solved

Comment: You can convert it to utc to make it return true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no experience with moment, but

```
const d1 = new Date('2070-07-27T21:59:59.999Z');
const d2 = new Date('2070-07-27T23:00:58.000Z');
console.log(d1.getDay()); // sunday
console.log(d2.getDay()); // monday
```

Thus, it's not a moment issue.

Edit: *Possible* solution. [Use the same timezone for both dates.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getUTCDay)

```
console.log(d1.getUTCDay() === d2.getUTCDay()); // true (same weekday)
```

or

```
console.log(
  (d1.getUTCDate() === d2.getUTCDate()) &&
  (d1.getUTCMonth() === d2.getUTCMonth()) &&
  (d1.getUTCFullYear() === d2.getUTCFullYear())
); // true (same date)
```

or

```
const moment = require('moment');

const d1 = new Date('2070-07-27T21:59:59.999Z');
const d2 = new Date('2070-07-27T23:00:58.000Z');

const isSame = moment(d1).isSame(moment(d2), 'day');
console.log(isSame); // false

const isSameFixed = moment(d1).utc().isSame(moment(d2).utc(), 'day');
console.log(isSameFixed); // true
```

Comment: Thanks, can you  propose a solution though, Finding if two dates are same, in this scenario

Comment: Sorry, extended my answer.

Comment: I am checking for same `date` and not same `day`, sorry, i think `"day"` and `"date"` means same in this context

Comment: Updated. You can also include `UTCHours`, `UTCMinutes` etc.

Comment: Updated. Added `moment` solution.